# Telegram links doesn't works as expected

Tags: telegram

In windows OS when you open a telegram link for example `tg://resolve?domain=botfather` it will run telegram and open that channel or chat. In Ubuntu telegram runs but channel not opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this solution, same issue:  https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/2630

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Instead reproduce the necessary information/procedure here as answer and base it on the link. If for some reason the URL dies your post becomes useless. Meanwhile wait until you have enough reputation for commenting on questions.